# Expressing the largest floating point value in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

*How to express the largest floating point value (for `FLOAT8`) in PostgreSQL?*

I need it to replace `'Infinity'::FLOAT8` during conversion to `jsonb` field values, because json [does not allow NaN and infinity values](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).

C++ has `numeric_limits<double>::max()`. Is there something equivalent in PostgreSQL?

(I'm using the latest PostgreSQL 11/12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constant for that in PostgreSQL, but if your architecture uses IEEE floating precision values, the maximum should be `1.7976931348623158e308`.

Maybe it would be a good idea to use a value that's larger than any reasonable value, but obviously artificial, like `1e300`.